# Ubuntu 12.04 LAN Connection

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I installed ubuntu 12.04, dualbooted with windows 8.
I access Internet via proxy server using ethernet hub.
It works well with Windows 8 but in Ubuntu, is says wire disconnected. How?

Comment: Do you disconnect your wire when you boot with Ubuntu? :D Seriously, you should give more details if you want any help, like details of your configuration...

Comment: Nope. Configuration like?

Comment: Like what's your network card? What's the result of `ifconfig`? What have you already tried?

Comment: ifcofig:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:fe:b5:bc:50:87  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:47

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:281336 (281.3 KB)  TX bytes:281336 (281.3 KB)

Comment: wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:53:2e:0a:67:98  
          inet addr:10.144.31.230  Bcast:10.144.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8a53:2eff:fe0a:6798/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:138564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:73687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:122186188 (122.1 MB)  TX bytes:15112092 (15.1 MB)

Comment: What model of DELL is this machine? Perhaps there is a specific driver that needs loading for this type of machine

Comment: Dell XPS 15 it is

Comment: In ifconfig, it says TX BYTES and RX BYTES are 0 for eth0.Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Wire disconnected sounds like the driver for your network card has loaded but the firmware is missing.

Many cards rely on extra software to be loaded to actually "do the work" for them, this makes producing the cards easier and cheaper and also makes upgrades easier as it's just a software upgrade rather than flashing your cards bios. This type of card requires that you obtain the additional software (known as "firmware") and putting it in the correct place (on Linux this is normally /lib/firmware).

Look in /var/log/dmesg to see if there are any messages relating to your network card as it may tell you what file is missing.

Comment: [   15.747871] r8169 0000:06:00.0: eth0: link down
[   15.747878] r8169 0000:06:00.0: eth0: link down
[   15.748169] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   15.748456] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready

Comment: Is that the problem?

Comment: Do you have the package "linux-firmware" installed? It includes the firmware for your card and may fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, it's installed.